# How to enable a PHP function (file_put_contents) that is disabled by default?

Tags: php

The file_put_contents() function is disabled for some reason on my server. How do I enable it? And how do I enable/disable PHP functions in general?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if your on webhosting then it's disabled for a reason'; you could message their help desk for assistance on this matter. They could help you further, perhaps not enabling this option. But explain why this is disabled.

If you have access to your `php.ini` then you can enable the function through that.

Else, you COULD  (not saying it will 100% work) try the following: 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php

Comment: You can also try to set this variable with htaccess: http://davidwalsh.name/php-values-htaccess

Comment: I'm hosting my app on Amazon Web Services, I have full control of the system. Where exactly do I enable file_put_contents in php.ini? I tried to look for 'file_put_contents', but there is no such field.